# Metrizable compact questions related to Cantor set and two arrows space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

1. Prove that any metrizable compactum is a continuous image of a Cantor perfect set.
2. What is the cardinality of a compact metrizable without isolated points?
3. Is the space “two arrows of Alexandrov” a continuous image of a Cantor perfect set?

"two arrows of Alexandrov" = $\{0\}\times(0,1]\cup\{1\}\times[0,1)$.

I know that the first question can be found in some books but I can't find the proof

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: 2 is continuum (size of $\Bbb R$) of course. See the Cantor set and $[0,1]$. 3 is no, as the continuous image of a metric compact I’m is still metrisable. 1 has many proofs and will depend on your background and known theory  you should clarify what theorems you already covered before this problem.

Comment: The answers [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1873116/general-structure-of-the-proof-that-every-compact-metric-space-is-the-continuous?rq=1) outline a proof of (1). [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/201922/proof-that-a-perfect-set-is-uncountable/202054#202054) answers (2). (1) answers (3) once you prove that the double arrow space is not metrizable; you can do this by showing that it is not second countable.